# Question about the identity of $2^{2^n}$

Tags: exponentiation

Is this identity true: $2^{2^n}= 4^n$? 
I believe this is true as far as I know.
Sorry this is the only place to ask.

Is there another identity for $2^{2^n}$ which I can simplify to?

Comment: The ordinary meaning of $2^{2^n}$ is $2^{(2^n)}$, in which case the equality fails.

Comment: But isn't 2^(2^n) = (2^2)^n? Is there another identity for $2^{2^n}$?

Comment: $2^{2^n}=2^{(2^n)}=4^{(2^{n-1})}=4^{2^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 2):

No.  In standard usage, $2^{2^n}$ means $2^{(2^n)}$, not $(2^2)^n$.

Notice that $(a^b)^c$ is equal to $a^{bc}$, whereas $a^{(b^c)}$ cannot be similarly simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $n = 0$. The equation would not work.

Comment: but it seems to hold for n >0 though.

Comment: @tony1 $2^{2^3} = 256$, $4^3 = 64$

Comment: @tony1 This works for $n=1,2$ and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What happens when $n = 0$?

**Advice:**

Also, before asking simple questions like these, it is a good idea to try out a few values.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler — i.e., a computer program that translates a program written in a high-level language into a machine-level language — treats a^b^c as a^(b^c) rather than as (a^b)^c, (as the OP speculated).